I want to increase a sample number from the last used value rather than the highest in the dataset
I have a QField project with multiple users syncing data to one cloud project. I would like to auto-increment the sample number to the last used value of the particular user rather than the last highest number in the dataset. Essentially User 1 has sample numbers 1000, 1001 etc. User 2 has 2001 , 2002 etc. after syncing to the cloud User 1 is defaulted to sample 2003 for each entry instead of 1003.
